# If $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is finitely generated, can we write $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha+ \cdots + \mathbb{Z}\alpha^k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

This is a very basic question in algebraic integers. I was trying to prove an implication of algebraic integers in my own way.

(i) $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraic integer.

(ii) There is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-sub-module of $\mathbb{C}$ which contains the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

**Arguments in proving $(ii)\Rightarrow (i)$** Any notes on algebraic integers give proof of this which I can see but my question is about following arguments:

(1) Let $S\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-sub-module which contains $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

(2) Since submodule of finitely generated module over PID is finitely generated, so $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is such!

(3) Then $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha+ \cdots + \mathbb{Z}\alpha^k$ for some $k\ge 1$.

(4) Hence $\alpha^{k+1}=c_0 + c_1\alpha+\cdots + c_k\alpha^k$.

(5) Hence $\alpha$ satisfies a monic polynomial $x^{k+1}-(c_kx^k+\cdots + c_0)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: (3) $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is finitely generated, but is it necessary that it has a set of generators in the form of $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots\}$? At least for me it is not that obvious :(

Comment: Notice that the body of your question does not include a question, or rather, it has a question different from the one in the title.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

If $\mathbb{Z}[ \alpha ]$ is finitely generated,then there are polynomials $f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m \in \mathbb{Z}[x] $,such that $\mathbb{Z}[ \alpha ]=\mathbb{Z}f_1(\alpha)+\mathbb{Z}f_2(\alpha)+\cdots+\mathbb{Z}f_m(\alpha)$.

Let $n$=max{ deg $f_1,\cdots, $deg $f_m$},it's easily see that $\mathbb{Z}[ \alpha ]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha+\cdots+\mathbb{Z}\alpha^n$.